# What is the exact reference of "External" in android Studio's DownloadManger class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, reference, android-download-manager

---

---

As using `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir` and `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` while working with `DowloadManager` in "android studio", I noticed that there's something weird with these two methods.

Do `ExternalFilesDir` and `ExternalPublicDir` refer to some location on an external removable memory, such as sdCards; or just to that on the internal memory of the device but out of the app's directory?

I searched for the answer on google's developers' site but did not find the proper answer,unfortunately.

***Any help is appreciated.***

---

---

Comment: In Android parlance, "external" refers to locations that are not in apps' private internal storage. That does not necessarily mean _removable_ storage, which it seems you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mike M's comment on the question:

> In Android parlance, "external" refers to locations that are not in
>   apps' private internal storage. That does not necessarily mean
>   removable storage, ... .

*And it, absolutely, is correct.*